# log4j output displays unicode hexcharacter output

Tags: java, unicode, log4j

I have a logger statement that displays the log in Unicode hex character.
    Can you please advice how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

```
log.info("Process completed; runid={}; Time Taken(ms)={};" + runid +
                    (System.currentTimeMillis() -   
 sTime_tds));
```

Process completed; runid=={}; Time
    Taken(ms)={};10

Answer (score 0):

the correct use of the log4j placeholders would be:

`log.info("Process completed; runid={}; Time Taken(ms)={};", runid,
                    (System.currentTimeMillis() - sTime_tds));`

for reference: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/messages.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried it the below way and got this error

Comment: [exec]     [javac] symbol  : method info(java.lang.String,short,long)
     [exec]     [javac] location: class com.freddiemac.msof.fire.common.util.Logger
     [exec]     [javac]          log.info("Process completed; runid={}; Time Taken(ms)={};", runid,

Comment: long sTime_tds = System.currentTimeMillis();
      short runid = 1;

Comment: Using the log4j-1.2.12 jar

Comment: oh ok, I would use slf4j then, if you specifically want to use apache log4j-1.2 then you'd need to do the string message concatenation manually.

Comment: Can you please provide an example

Comment: e.g. 
`log.info("Process completed; runid={" + runid + "}; Time Taken(ms)={" +                     (System.currentTimeMillis() - sTime_tds) + " };");`

Comment: Thank you so much, but my output displays something like this  Process completed&#x3b; runid&#x3d;&#x7b;1&#x7d;&#x3b; Time Taken&#x28;ms&#x29;&#x3d;&#x7b;0 &#x7d;&#x3b;

Comment: This is my log4j  configuration <appender name="to-console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%x [%d{MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%t] %-5p [%c] - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

Comment: what if you add `<param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />`

Comment: Also, if we need to use slf4j jar any specific version?

Comment: looks like 1.7.21 is the latest, e.g. http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j

Comment: <appender name="to-console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%x [%d{MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%t] %-5p [%c] - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

Comment: can you also try with
`<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
  <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
    <param name="ConversionPattern"
           value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSZ} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>`?

Comment: Still displaying in the same way

Comment: I tried adding sl4j in classpath <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/JARS/lib/log4j-1.2.12.jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/JARS/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar"/>  and in pom.xml, it still doesn't recognize this jar. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: <dependency>  
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>  
     <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>  
     <version>1.7.7</version>  
       <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
         <groupId>*</groupId>
         <artifactId>*</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
       </exclusions>      
 </dependency>

Comment: Can you please assist

Comment: Please assist. why it doesn't work even after specifying encoding utf